# Java Concurrency - best complete tutorial and sample code needed

Tags: java, concurrency

Can you please suggest some good tutorial for Java Concurrency. Where can i get some sample code also.

Comment: Check this post about concurrency basics. 

http://walivi.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/concurrency-in-java-a-beginners-introduction/

Comment: Check this out : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html

Comment: https://github.com/tanship/ExamplesThreads

Answer (score 14):

This is also a nice series of articles covering the topic:

http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/05/java-concurrency-part-1-threads/ 
http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/05/java-concurrency-part-2-manipulate-threads/ 
http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/08/java-concurrrency-synchronization-locks/ 
http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/08/java-concurrency-part-4-semaphores/ 
http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-5-monitors-locks-and-conditions/ 
http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-atomic-variables/ 
http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-7-executors-and-thread-pools/

Answer (score 3):

First google link:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/